# Yii2: Setting default values for all fields of a model

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, model, yii2

I'm trying to find a way to set a default value for any field (not filled by user input) in Yii2 as to avoid a "Cannot be NULL" database exception.

Is there any way that this could be done?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the default values to the model database table

Than use loadDefaultValues() when creating an instance of your model

```
$model = new Post();
$model->loadDefaultValues();
```

Comment: loadDefaultValues() used to load defalut values from db , " cannot be null" error occurs if there is no default value in batabase  not even null

Answer (score 5):

[Yii2 Default Validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#default) - in model validation rules pass all attributes, which you want to be filled with default values, like:

```
[['attribute', 'second_attribute'], 'default', 'value' => 'something_here'],
```